# Give Warning for Certain Syntax

Tags: continuous-integration, git-merge, linter

I had an experience with slow sqlalchemy subquery using syntax `Query.select_from()`. Based on this experience, I want to get warning everytime certain syntax is used in our codebase. For example, when programmers add this code bellow, I want to get warnings.

```
q = session.query(Address).select_from(User).\
    join(User.addresses).\
    filter(User.name == 'ed')
```

Is there any linter or tools that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would set a pre-receive hook on the remote Git repo hosting server, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28416949/6309), in order to read the pushed files and grep for "`query.*\.select_from`": if detected, that hook would reject the push.

If you don't have access to the remote server (for instance GitHub), you would need to set a [webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) instead.

The alternative is to deploy a [`pre-push` hook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44255141/6309) to all clients, and do the check there, but that could be bypassed, or could be not deployed to everybody.
A server side hook / webhook is safer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think i will try pre-push hook first, then maybe set up webhook.